# main doesn't continue after pthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, pthreads, codeblocks

Im using Ubuntu 10.10, Code::Blocks with GCC 4.2.

I have written a code like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

void *thread1proc(void* param){
    while(true)
    cout << "1";

    return 0;
}

int main(){
    pthread_t thread1;

    pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,thread1proc,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread1,NULL);

    cout << "hello";
}
```

Main starts, creates the thread. But what is weird (for me) is main doesn't continue running. I expect to see "hello" message on screen and end of the program. Because in Windows, in Delphi it worked for me like that. If "main" is also a thread, why doesn't it continue running? Is it about POSIX threading?

Thank you.

Comment: For portability, explicitly create threads in a joinable state with `pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It stops because you call [pthread_join](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_join.html) and the thread you are joining "to" has an infinite loop.

From that link:

> The pthread_join() function suspends
>   execution of the calling thread until
>   the target thread terminates, unless
>   the target thread has already
>   terminated.

Comment: @Tolga: You can fire as many threads as you'd like. In your specific case, you'd have to fire them up before the call to pthread_join, because your thread hangs in an infinite loop. You need to study how the pthread library works... See here: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: @Tolga: pthreads and windows threads work fairly similarly.  Windows does not, however, have an equivalent to the join function ...

Comment: Isn't there any function like "resumeThread" as in Windows APIs? I don't want tp wait for end of thread.

Comment: Ok. I ve found the solution. I didn't use pthread_join function. I substituted while(true){}. And it looks thread continues working. I supposed, we needed pthread_join function to start the thread. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

`pthread_join` will block until `thread1` completes (calling `pthread_exit` or returning), which (as it has an infinite loop) it never will do.